# CustomContent in Primefaces selectOneMenu without persisting object

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am using the Primefaces SelectOneMenu (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) with the "Custom content" version as described in the demo.

The problem is that the columns only work if the actual value of the field, which is bound to the dropdown field, is of the type of the Object used as the `value`.

The following works (if `Bean.field` is of type `SelectObject`):

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.field}"
    var="x">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{valuesBean.getSelectItems()}" var="bt"
        itemLabel="#{bt.label}" itemValue="#{bt}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{x.value}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="xyz" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The following does NOT work (`Bean.field` of type `String`):

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.field}"
    var="x">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{valuesBean.getSelectItems()}" var="bt"
        itemLabel="#{bt.label}" itemValue="#{bt.value}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{x.value}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="xyz" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In the first version, the `xyz` is displayed as second column, in the second version it's not. The problem I have is that now I need to save an object of type `SelectObject` in the database although I could as well just save the String of the `value` field there.

Is there a nice way to handle this?

Comment: Try making the getter/setter for bean.field be of type Object e.g. setField(Object value), Object getField()

Comment: This conflicts with the fact that the `Bean` is a JPA-entity and the type `String` is reflected in the respective database column.

Comment: I worked around the problem by using the actual object as the type for `bean.field`. But I don't save it serialized anymore but use a `@OneToOne` instead. This works, although now I have the problem of many entries filling up my "Item"-table. Anyway, this can be "closed" now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Converter to convert the value of the selected menu item (bt.value) to that expected by the backing bean method tied to the p:selectOneMenu (bean.field).

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.field}" var="x" converter="yourconverterid">
```

Comment: I did/tried that. The basic functionality works, but the columns for the custom content don't work then. So either I have the primitive type for bean.field OR I can use custom content/columns. It seems I am not able to use both (which is exactly what I need).

Comment: The example in the PrimeFaces Showcase uses a converter with custom content. Please double-check that you dont have a defect. I typically find it useful to simplify things by making a simple test case (that stubs out data and doesnt integrate with the back end) when I run into issues like this. Note, make sure that anything you're trying to bind to in the select list is Serializable and that your backing bean is Serializable, if it is ViewScoped.

Comment: The converter and the "custom content" for displaying the dropdowns works, if and only if the field has the object type. It does NOT work if the field has a primitive type, e.g. just a String.

Comment: java.lang.String is an Object, not a primitive. Custom Content with a Converter should work; again, recommend you re-implement the solution using a simple test case to rule out you dont have a defect.

Comment: Yes, I did create a really simple example. The types of the bean property referenced in the `value` of the `SelectOneMenu` and of the `itemValue` of `selectItems` need to be the same. At the same time, that type is used to determine whether to display the separate columns ("custom content") or not. If the types are different, the validation fails _always_ (converter isn't even triggered), if I change the `itemValue` to the primitive type (or String), I don't have the custom content anymore but the labels from `itemLabel` instead.

Comment: OK, I think I get why it doesn't work: within the `column`s, JSF accesses the object defined in the `value` of the `selectOneMenu`. If that is not the object but just a reference to it, the columns obviously cannot be filled. A converter is only relevant if the `itemValue` of `selectItems` is of a differenty type than the `value` of the `selectOneMenu`. But as my problem is that I need that value to be of a certain type, it is irrelevant here.

Comment: As a side note: If I let my object extend `SelectItem`, the `p:selectOneMenu` doesn't work with customContent, either. It must be a class NOT extending the `SelectItem`.