# LazyInitializationException vs. Too many tables - better model?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, jboss7.x

for two days now I am trying to get my JSF+Primefaces/JBoss AS 7.1/Hibernate application to work and I am bouncing back and forth between `LazyInitializationException`s and `Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join` errors.

I will try to describe my current entity model as correct as possible.

I have a machine which consists of several modules. Every module is basically a tab in my web application and on this tab there are several fields in a form. The problem is with the dropdown fields. For those, I get the available options externally from a drools system which builds the options, depending on other fields in other modules. E.g. the available colors depend on the selected surface material and the dropdowns are created accordingly.

Now, due to a limitation in JSF/Primefaces, I need to save the selected dropdown value as objects in my module-entities. See [CustomContent in Primefaces selectOneMenu without persisting object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396172/customcontent-in-primefaces-selectonemenu-without-persisting-object) and [Disabling items with PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu with custom content / p:column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817760/disabling-items-with-primefaces-selectonemenu-with-custom-content-pcolumn) for questions I had/have which are about that.

So, for every DropDown field, I have a `@OneToOne` relation in the module entity class:

```
@Entity
public class PressureModule {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Machine                machine;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DropDownSelectItem     type         = DropDownSelectItem.getSelectOneItem();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DropDownSelectItem     pressureTop  = DropDownSelectItem.getSelectOneItem();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DropDownSelectItem     color        = DropDownSelectItem.getSelectOneItem();

    // getters, setters
}
```

And a single DopDownSelectItem:

```
@Entity
public class DropDownSelectItem implements Serializable, Comparable<DropDownSelectItem> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long              id;
    @Column
    private String            label;
    @Column
    private String            value;
    @Column
    private boolean           disabled;
    @Column
    private String            disabledReason;
}
```

Hibernate automatically creates the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `dropdownselectitem` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `disabledReason` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;


CREATE TABLE `pressuremodule` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `machine_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `pressuretop_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `color_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8E3D129AE7CE7BEF` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `dropdownselectitem` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8E3D129ABD1E6ED1` FOREIGN KEY (`pressuretop_id`) REFERENCES `dropdownselectitem` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8E3D129ABD1EE330` FOREIGN KEY (`color_id`) REFERENCES `dropdownselectitem` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8E3D129AC56471E2` FOREIGN KEY (`machine_id`) REFERENCES `machine` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

The dropdowns are filled with the following logic:

In the .xhtml:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.field}" var="x">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{dropDownValuesBean.getSelectItems()}" var="dd"
        itemLabel="#{dd.label}" itemValue="#{dd}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{x.label}" />
        <h:outputText value=" {#{x.value}}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And the DropDownValuesBean (shortened):

```
public List<PstSelectItem> getSelectItems(final String module, final String field) {

    knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    List<PstSelectItem> returnList;

    StatefulKnowledgeSession statefulKnowledgeSession = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    statefulKnowledgeSession.insert(sessionBean.getActiveMachine());
    statefulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules();
    Collection<FactHandle> handles = statefulKnowledgeSession.getFactHandles(new ClassObjectFilter(DropDownSelectItem.class));
    for (FactHandle handle : handles) {
        DropDownSelectItem selectItem = (DropDownSelectItem) statefulKnowledgeSession.getObject(handle);
        returnList.add(selectItem);
    }
    Collections.sort(returnList);
    return returnList;
}
```

The problem now is, that if I have many dropdown fields (we are talking about up to 150), the following exception occurs:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join
```

The reason is quite clear, I can understand the problem. Now, if I change the entities to use `@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`, I run into the famous `LazyInitializationException`. This is not really surprising.

When I search for solutions for this, I mostly get references to the `OpenSessionInView` filter which comes with the Spring framework. Since I don't use Spring and since I don't plan on introducing that dependency, I am a bit lost.

I already tried the following things:

- Using `@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)` in my DAOs: https://community.jboss.org/thread/177735
- Only storing references to the selected dropDown value (only selected String instead of the whole object) in the database - that fails because I cannot re-calculate the selected `DropDownSelectItem` from that String in the entity because I cannot inject the respective Drools-logic into the entity (`@Inject`ing is not supported in `@Entity`s)
- saving the serialized DropDownSelectItem in the database directly, but that leads to huge database tables (as every DropDown-item is saved in a blob) and I cannot get the selected value with a simple SQL (needed for reporting purposes)

Environment:

- JBoss AS 7.1.0
- Primefaces 3.2
- MySQL 5.5
- JDK 6

Any ideas? If more information regarding the configuration or anything is needed, I'd be happy to provide those!

Comment: Why would you have so many dropdown lists that you should save on your database? They come from the database once, and that's how they should be. Try to put all your lists/maps that fill your dropdowns in an Application Managed Bean (+1 to reuse). Also, you can leverage the data for the dependent dropdrownlist (like State and City) using a cache system like JBoss Cache or EhCache.

Comment: I won't actually save the dropdown lists but only the respective selected value. But I do have quite many dropdown fields, that is the problem.

Comment: What I don't understand is why would you need `PressureModule` and `DropDownSelectItem`as `@Entity` for hibernate. They are plain POJOs that can be filled from database values, they do not need to interact with your db directly.

Comment: Where are they interacting with the database? Or do you mean my comment with the injection? That is, because if I only saved the selected dropdown value as plain String, I could somehow get the respective DropDownSelectItem, which I can't. That would be the only place where the POJOs would interact with the database.

Comment: It would be good to see how do you fill one dropdownlist.

Comment: I added the logic for getting the DropDownSelectItems to the original question.